# Get value of drop down menu and save as variable in PHP

Tags: php, select

I want to get the selected value of a drop down menu and save it as a variable. I tried the following as documented in another post, but it seems not working: `echo $selected = $_POST['<?php $as->my_name(); ?>'];`

Drop down:

```
<select name="<?php $as->my_name(); ?>"> 
                    <option value="">Select this</option>
                    <option value="91"<?php $mb->state('91'); ?>>91</option>
                    <option value="90"<?php $mb->state('90'); ?>>90</option>
                    <option value="89"<?php $mb->state('89'); ?>>89</option>
                    <option value="88"<?php $mb->state('88'); ?>>88</option>
                    <option value="87"<?php $mb->state('87'); ?>>87</option>
                    <option value="86"<?php $mb->state('86'); ?>>86</option>
                    <option value="85"<?php $mb->state('85'); ?>>85</option>
                    <option value="84"<?php $mb->state('84'); ?>>84</option>
                    <option value="83"<?php $mb->state('83'); ?>>83</option>
                    <option value="82"<?php $mb->state('82'); ?>>82</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try using `echo $selected = $_POST[$as->my_name()];`.

Comment: BTW, I think that if you check the generated code for your page, your select has no name, since you didn't echo anything (but I don't really know what `$as->my_name();` does really).

Comment: that does not output the required value actually. You'll find the PHP here, line 320: https://github.com/tagDiv/wp_booster_project/blob/master/wp_booster/wp-admin/content-metaboxes/td_set_post_settings.php

Answer (score 0):

**Post the form:**

You have to put the select option within form tags

```
<form method="post">

    <select name="example">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />

 </form>
```

**Get the posted value:**

To get the value of this example you can use:

```
<?php
    $selected = $_POST['example'];
    echo $selected;
?>
```

To get the value in your case:

```
<select name="<?php echo $as->my_name(); ?>">
    <option value="test">test</option>
</select>

<?php
    $selected = $_POST[$as->my_name()];
    echo $selected;
?>
```